# Save result from nltk.tree.Tree to list in Python

Tags: python, list, tree, nltk

I have a problem where I want to save the result of type nltk.tree.Tree into a list. Here is my code from the parsed result :

```
for result in range(len(parsing)):
    print(parsing[result])
    Tree.fromstring(str(parsing[result])).pretty_print()
>>>
(S
  (SUB (FNOM (NND seorang) (NP mahasiswa)))
  (PRE (FVERB (MD boleh) (VB meminjam)))
  (OBJ (FNOM (CD beberapa) (NP buku))))
                         S                                    
          _______________|____________________________         
        SUB                   PRE                    OBJ      
         |                     |                      |        
        FNOM                 FVERB                   FNOM     
    _____|_______         _____|______          ______|____    
  NND            NP      MD           VB       CD          NP 
   |             |       |            |        |           |   
seorang      mahasiswa boleh       meminjam beberapa      buku
```

What I expect is that the results in the form of a tree can be stored in the form of a list like this:

```
['S', ['SUB', ['FNOM', [('NND', 'seorang'), ('NP', 'mahasiswa')]]], ['PRE', ['FVERB', [('MD', 'boleh'), ('VB', 'meminjam')]]], ['OBJ', ['FNOM', [('CD', 'beberapa'), ('NP', 'buku')]]]]
```

Or similar output in the form of a list.
For additional information the following is the output type of the result of the variable "parsing" :

```
print(type(parsing[0]))
>>>
<class 'nltk.tree.Tree'>
```

My problem why I want to change to "list" is because I can't retrieve the result from the tree like "S", "SUB","PRE","OBJ", "FNOM", etc. All I can take from the tree are the words in the list. Here is an example :

```
print(str(parsing[0]) + '\n')
print(str(parsing[0][0]) + '\n')
print(str(parsing[0][0][0]) + '\n')
print(str(parsing[0][0][0][0]) + '\n')
print(str(parsing[0][0][0][0][0]) + '\n')
>>>
(S
  (SUB (FNOM (NND seorang) (NP mahasiswa)))
  (PRE (FVERB (MD boleh) (VB meminjam)))
  (OBJ (FNOM (CD beberapa) (NP buku))))  #How to get "S"

(SUB (FNOM (NND seorang) (NP mahasiswa))) #How to get "SUB"

(FNOM (NND seorang) (NP mahasiswa)) #How to get "FNOM"

(NND seorang) #How to get "NND"

seorang #Showing word but not tag
```

Is there any workaround I can do or how should I make this problem solved? If there is information that I have not provided, please let me know so I can correct my question.

Anyway my english language is bad so please understand.
Thank you. ^-^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sir, you can do it like this, but the computation isn't the best

```
list_test = []
for result in range(len(parsing)) :
    temp_list1 = []
    
    temp_list1.append(parsing[0].label())
    for item in parsing[result]:
        temp_list2 = []
        
        for words in item:
            temp_list3 = []
            temp_list3.append(words.label())
            temp_list4 = []
            for word in words:
                
                temp_list4.append((word.label(),word[0]))
                
            temp_list3.append(temp_list4)
            temp_list2.append(item.label())
            temp_list2.append(temp_list3)
        
        
        temp_list1.append(temp_list2)   
    list_test.append(temp_list1)

for result in list_test :
    print(result)
    print("\n")
```

and you will get something like this :

```
['S', ['SUB', ['FNOM', [('NND', 'seorang'), ('NP', 'mahasiswa')]]], ['PRE', ['FVERB', [('MD', 'boleh'), ('VB', 'meminjam')]]], ['OBJ', ['FNOM', [('CD', 'beberapa'), ('NP', 'buku')]]]]
```